# iPhone: UITextField default text problem

Tags: ios, ios4

In my custom table cell I want to show some default text in my UITextField like "enter your name" and when user starts to edit the cell I want that text stays there and un-editable, and the editing starts  just where the default text ends. Can I do this easily?

I can do that by putting a label on the left and a textfield on the right, but then I have to calculate eachtime how long is the default text(which can be different for each field) and custom create a textfield in that lenght to fit in.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the label calculate the size. Just set the label's text then have the label size to fit, and slide the UITextField right up to the edge of the label. If I have a trailing space in the label's text it looks great.

Something like this:

```
UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 550.0, 28.0)];
[nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Bold" size:24.0]];
[nameLabel setText:@"Name: "];
[nameLabel sizeToFit];
[self addSubview:nameLabel];
[nameLabel release];
UITextField *nameTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(nameLabel.frame.size.width + nameLabel.frame.origin.x, 0.0, 550.0 - nameLabel.frame.size.width, nameLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

**Edit to answer the comment about special cases:** In special cases such as very long labels you'll have to add additional code. For example you could check the width after the `sizeToFit` call, and if it exceeds a certain width, rebuild the label with multiple lines, smaller font, etc. Unfortunately, if you need to account for special cases, you'll have to do extra coding work.

Comment: tnx this looks very helpful, but what if sometimes the label text is very long and these times I want it adjust its font or truncate lines to allow for some space for text input?

Comment: Yes, you can set up interface elements in Interface Builder then adjust them with methods like setFrame and sizeToFit in code, as long as you connect them to IBOutlets.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a `UITextField`, you can hook into the `UITextFieldDelegate` [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html) to check the text of the text field at different states.  For example, when the `UITextField` is becomes editable, and whenever the text in the text field is changed.

The two you might be interested in are:

```objective-c
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

Using these, you can easily have the `placeholder` property of `UITextField` contain whatever text you would like to use, then when the user begins to edit the field, have `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` fill in the textfield text with the placeholder text, then monitor the text at every character the user inputs using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to not let the user delete the placeholder text you've input for them manually.

Comment: why not only the second method u mentioned isn't enough here?

Comment: the first delegate method enables you to replace the placeholder text (the greyed out text) with actual text in the text field.  The second delegate method will prevent the user from deleting the text you input manually using the first delegate method, which is the desired result it seemed you were trying to achieve.